# TCPServer in ruby, Code is stuck

Tags: ruby

im building a small game in ruby to practice programming, so far everything has went well but im trying to implement multiplayer support, i can connect to the server and i can send information but when I try to read form the server it just freezes and my screen goes completely black. and i cant find the cause, ive read the documentation for the gem im using for TCP and i dont know, maybe i missed something, but if any of you have some insight I would really appreciate it

heres the repo if this code isnt enough

https://github.com/jaypitti/ruby-2d-gosu-game

heres the client side code

```
class Client
  include Celluloid::IO
  def initialize(server, port)
    begin
      @socket = TCPSocket.new(server, port)
    rescue
      $error_message = "Cannot find game server."
    end
  end
  def send_message(message)
    @socket.write(message) if @socket
  end
  def read_message
    @socket.readpartial(4096) if @socket
  end
end
```

heres the gameserver

```
require 'celluloid/autostart'
require 'celluloid/io'
class Server
  include Celluloid::IO
  finalizer :shutdown
  def initialize(host, port)
    puts "Starting Server on #{host}:#{port}."
    @server = TCPServer.new(host, port)
    @objects = Hash.new
    @players = Hash.new
    async.run
  end
  def shutdown
    @server.close if @server
  end
  def run
    loop { async.handle_connection @server.accept }
  end
  def handle_connection(socket)
    _, port, host = socket.peeraddr
    user = "#{host}:#{port}"
    puts "#{user} has joined the arena."
    loop do
      data = socket.readpartial(4096)
      data_array = data.split("\n")
      if data_array and !data_array.empty?
        begin
          data_array.each do |row|
            message = row.split("|")
            if message.size == 10
              case message[0] 
              when 'obj'
                @players[user] = message[1..9] unless @players[user]
                @objects[message[1]] = message[1..9]
              when 'del'
                @objects.delete message[1]
              end
            end
            response = String.new
            @objects.each_value do |obj|
              (response << obj.join("|") << "\n") if obj
            end
            socket.write response
          end
        rescue Exception => exception
          puts exception.backtrace
        end
      end # end data
    end # end loop
  rescue EOFError => err
    player = @players[user]
    puts "#{player[3]} has left"
    @objects.delete player[0]
    @players.delete user
    socket.close
  end
end
server, port = ARGV[0] || "0.0.0.0", ARGV[1] || 1234
supervisor = Server.supervise(server, port.to_i)
trap("INT") do
  supervisor.terminate
  exit
end
sleep
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it just freezes and my screen goes completely black. and i cant find the cause

A good trick you can look at is attaching to your process with either [rbspy](https://github.com/rbspy/rbspy) or [rbtrace](https://github.com/tmm1/rbtrace) to see that is going on when it is stuck.

You can also try first reducing dependencies here a bit and doing this with a simple threadpool prior to going full async with celluloid or event machine.

Comment: That’s what I ended up doing, didn’t attach to it with anything but I just decided to start from te beginning again and trace everything that was happening, turned out to be server side, I was missing some numbers so it was returning bad data in turn messing up my render

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should not be rescuing `Exception` all over the place. Wrapping long begin rescue blocks around nested iterators is begging for trouble.

It sounds like a threading issues, memory and/or CPU but that's just a guess. Try to monitor your resources or use some performance checking gems. But for the love of Satoshi Nakamoto, please write some test coverage and see your methods fail miserably, then fix them!

Some of these may help:

```
group :development do
  gem 'bullet', require: false
  gem 'flamegraph', require: false
  gem 'memory_profiler', require: false
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', require: false
  gem 'seed_dump'
  gem 'stackprof', require: false
  gem 'traceroute', require: false
end
```